# XML tree like document to display Organizational charts?

Tags: xml, orgchart

I am trying to create an XML Tree like structure that will be used to display Org Charts using some JavaScript frameworks.

the data looks like this all employees reporting to the director who is reporting to Vice president who is then reporting to functional Vice president. I have like 7000 unique employee in the database each with a record.

the tree should open like this --

1. all Function VP in the database.
2. Then display all VP reporting to the Function VP
3. Directors reporting to VP. 
   4.and then the employee
   record.

I have tried to come up with the below XML document that will help me achieve that. Is there a better way or are there any improvements you can suggest to the below XML tree like structure ?

```
<BusinessDirection>
  <func_VP>
    <funcvp_Name>Functional VP 1</funcvp_Name>
     <DirectReports>
      <VP>
        <vp_name>VP 1</vp_name>
         <Director>
            <Director_name>Director 1</Director_name>
               <EmployeeRecord>
                   <name>XYZ</name>
                   <serialnum>123</serialnum>
                   <email>xyz@domain.com</email>
               </EmployeeRecord>
         </Director>  
      </VP> 
    </DirectReports>
  </func_VP>


    <func_VP>
    <funcvp_Name>Functional VP 1</funcvp_Name>
     <DirectReports>
      <VP>
        <vp_name>VP 2</vp_name>
         <Director>
            <Director_name>Director 1</Director_name>
               <EmployeeRecord>
                   <name>XYZ</name>
                   <serialnum>123</serialnum>
                   <email>xyz@domain.com</email>
               </EmployeeRecord>
         </Director>  
      </VP> 
    </DirectReports>
  </func_VP>


    <func_VP>
    <funcvp_Name>Functional VP 2</funcvp_Name>
     <DirectReports>
      <VP>
        <vp_name>VP 3</vp_name>
         <Director>
            <Director_name>Director1</Director_name>
               <EmployeeRecord>
                   <name>XYZ</name>
                   <serialnum>123</serialnum>
                   <email>xyz@domain.com</email>
               </EmployeeRecord>
         </Director>  
      </VP> 
    </DirectReports>
  </func_VP>
</BusinessDirection>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following XML structure is from GetOrgChart javascript widget

```
<people>
<person name="Boss" phone="079 0616 3133" image="images/p-16.jpg" addres="58 Copthorne Way, CAMER, DA13 3GN" website="CardTribune.co.uk">
<person name="Jacob Henderson" phone="078 4750 2362" image="images/p-15.jpg" dateOfBirth="December 11, 1943" userName="Stivider"/>
<person name="Mason Siebenhaar" phone="079 3176 6188" image="images/p-14.jpg"/>
<person name="Manuel Beekman" phone="079 0346 5377" image="images/p-10.jpg" CVV2="939"/>
<person name="Barbara Mathis" phone="078 3998 6738" image="images/p-9.jpg" GUID="13a75b86-b9a1-40aa-8972-31a4ed573ab6">
<person name="Maude Hurst" phone="070 2655 0635" image="images/p-1.jpg" CVC2="108"/>
<person name="Margaret Hawkins" phone="070 6786 6047" image="images/p-7.jpg" mail="MargaretJHawkins@teleworm.us"/>
<person name="Jean Pitts" phone="078 6013 1878" image="images/p-5.jpg" mail="JeanWPitts@jourrapide.com"/>
</person>
<person name="Melissa Byler" phone="070 0640 9727" image="images/p-3.jpg" NINO="ZM 64 97 42 A"/>
<person name="Virgil Lee" phone="078 7598 6890" image="images/p-2.jpg" Visa="4556 4749 0420 0422"/>
<person name="Anthony Andres" phone="077 2935 5027" image="images/p-4.jpg" MasterCard="5166 1409 9098 3242"/>
</person>
</people>
```

Hope it will get you started